# Rewrite Rule to Redirect index.php to www

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have come across three different options for doing a 301 redirect from index.php to root.

Option 1: **Redirect index.php to www**

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [L,R=301]
```

Option 2: **Redirect index.php to www**

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Option 3: **Redirect index.php to www**

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Can anyone please help me understand the difference in the above three substitute options? In rewrite rule, what will be the impact of having:

```
/  
/$1
https://www.domain.co.uk/$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first option redirects `index.php` (from root level **only**) to `/`.
Example: `http://www.domain.com/index.php` becomes `http://www.domain.com/`.

The second option redirects `index.php` to its root folder.
Example: `http://www.domain.com/x/z/index.php` becomes `http://www.domain.com/x/z/`.

The third option is equivalent to first option **even if it has syntax errors** and won't work (`$1` is null since no group is captured in rule).

**Conclusion** (redirect `index.php` from root level to `/` root)
If i had to do it myself, the code would look like this

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule . / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed reply with examples, really helpful!